# Creating a calendar in Java

Tags: java, calendar, java1.4

I am trying to create a visual calendar with java, however I have no clue where to begin. I have to stay in java 1.4.2, so I'm limited as to what I can use. I'd like to make it look like this:

```
September:

S M T W T F S
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9 ...

October:

S M T W T F S
    1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 .....
```

Any idea as to where I can begin on this?

Comment: Is this a homework or some exercise? If not, then why not search for an already made component?

Comment: It's a homework assignment and I can't seem to find any other starting off points..

Comment: Take a look at the official tutorial for `Swing`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ and look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html especially to build your layout.

Comment: How could anybody be teaching/taking a course that requires Java 1.4!!?!!

Comment: @jahroy because there's people that loves to live in prehistoric times =\. I bet this teacher also thinks scriptlets are the top technology for Java web applications.

Comment: I don't know about Java 1.4, but in 1.7 I would tell you to look into a Grid Layout. First you add a JPanel with a grid layout to the center of the JFrame's border layout, then you have your program automatically fill in the dates. If you want to be able to switch between months, you could add JButtons to the bottom up the Border Layout in the JFrame.